# Android ADT aligning text in button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, alignment

[image]

And this is the xml tag:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="@string/Button" />
```

It supposed to be "Button" and not "But"...

So what is the problem?

Comment: check if the string Button in strings.xml is not But

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? because sometimes it shows text righalign but on emulator or device it show text in centre .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue a time ago, switching to a different *Android api level* from `Graphical Layout` seemed to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just put `android:text="Button"`   or in string.xml put your text